# Numpy put .txt integervalues into an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i want to read in a .txt file and put the items in an array.

the array should look like this:

```
[[0.01, 1.1],

[0.02, 1.105],

[0.03, 1.11]]
```

The .txt file looks like these:
[My txt file](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4636/ahdqeqh2_png.htm)

I want to make a FFT with numpy. thats my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[0.01, 1.1],
                 [0.02, 1.05],
                 [0.03, 1.11]])


t        = data[:,0]
signal_t = data[:,1]

dt = t[1]-t[0]

f        = np.fft.fftfreq(t.size, dt)
signal_f = np.fft.fft(signal_t)*dt

plt.figure()
plt.stem(np.fft.fftshift(f), np.fft.fftshift(np.abs(signal_f)))
plt.show()
```

Until now i typed the Values manuel by hand in the array. Now i want that my program read in the .txt file and put the Integeritems (Not "Zeit" and "Signal") in the array and do the FFT with the values.

Hope you can help me

THanks :-)

Comment: Have a look at `numpy.loadtxt`.

Comment: `data = np.loadtxt(file,skiprows=1)` will read the numbers and skip the header line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42320090/python-readin-txt-and-put-in-an-array-with-numpy  is asking about a similar file, same headers, but is tab separated.