# Python readin .txt and put in an array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i want to create an array with numpy.
The base is a .txt file which is given in the following form:
[image]

i tried it with loadtxt:

```
data = np.loadtxt("myfile.txt",delimiter='\n',skiprows = 1)
```

The first row with "Zeit" and "Signal" should be skipped i only need the array in this form:

[[0, 1], [0.01, 2], [0.02, 3]]

The Values from "Zeit" and "Signal are seperated with a tab.

i got this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: The delimiter in this case is whitespace, not a newline. Remove the parameter for delimiter, as the default value is any whitespace.

Comment: `delimiter` is for separating columns, yet you pass it a newline. Try removing that, the default behaviour should work in your case.

Comment: For tab separated use `delimiter='\t'`

Comment: @hpaulj I'm almost 100% that the default ("any whitespace") works on tabs

Comment: I tried it without the delimiter, but the same error is incoming:

Comment: You are having problems reading this file with `readlines`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317644/readin-a-txt-file-and-put-the-elements-in-a-list-python.  Switching to `loadtxt` isn't going help.  You need to solve the original problem

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318717/numpy-put-txt-integervalues-into-an-array has  a 'Zeit SIgnal' headed file?

Comment: @hpaulj they are common enough words in German ;-))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you shouldn't be passing the `delimiter='\n'` argument. As I am looking at the [loadtxt documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), this argument seems to specify the delimiter of values on a line, not a delimiter of lines. ...and calling the same function without that argument worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you run the following and report back what it returns? Specifically, what's in `bag`?

```
bag = []
i = 0
def probe(bit):
    global i
    i += 1
    try:
        return float(bit)
    except:
        bag.append((i, bit))
        return np.nan

data = np.loadtxt('myfile.txt', skiprows=1, converters={0:probe, 1:probe})
```

ok, try:

```
import itertools
data = np.loadtxt(itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: len(x.split())!=2, open('myfile.txt')), skiprows=1)
```

Comment: return float(bit):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Nekoso oops, sorry, try removing the colon.

Comment: ok i tried it again:ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 7

Comment: @Nekoso Well, then. Go ahead and look at line 7. Besides that you should still tell us what `bag` looks like now (after running 'np.loadtxt')

Comment: My .txt file has got only 6 rows, if i add another one then it returns Wrong number of columns at line 8. i cant find any items in bag

Comment: @Nekoso Could you try what I put at the end of the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

```
data = np.genfromtxt("myfile.txt",skip_header = 1,dtype=None,)
data = [list(i) for i in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly tried to recreate your file as

```
Zeit\tSignal
0.01\t1.1
0.02\t1.105
0.03\t1.108
0.04\t1.2
0.05\t1.205
0.06\t1.209
```

loaded with:

```
data=np.loadtxt('test.txt', skiprows=1)
```

and got:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'0.01\\t1.1'
```

Changing the string `\t` to real tabs (hard to convey this with copy-n-paste):

```
In [474]: data=np.loadtxt('test.txt', skiprows=1)
In [475]: data
Out[475]: 
array([[ 0.01 ,  1.1  ],
       [ 0.02 ,  1.105],
       [ 0.03 ,  1.108],
       [ 0.04 ,  1.2  ],
       [ 0.05 ,  1.205],
       [ 0.06 ,  1.209]])
```

Make sure that your file contains just these characters (with spaces or real tabs between columns).  It should plain ASCII, not RTF or other formatted test.

It may be worth trying a string dtype just to see if just a few funny chacacters are giving a problem, eg.

```
In [478]: data=np.loadtxt('test.txt', dtype=str)
In [479]: data
Out[479]: 
array([["b'Zeit'", "b'Signal'"],
       ["b'0.01'", "b'1.1'"],
       ["b'0.02'", "b'1.105'"],
       ["b'0.03'", "b'1.108'"],
       ["b'0.04'", "b'1.2'"],
       ["b'0.05'", "b'1.205'"],
       ["b'0.06'", "b'1.209'"]], 
      dtype='<U9')
```